# Boinc permissions problem on OS X

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, boinc

I installed boinc 6.10.21 on my OS X 10.5 in order to upgrade from a 6.6 version that I was running today, and I am the admin user, and I was logged in as the admin user. As I was installing 6.10.21 I was asked if non admin users should be allowed to use Boinc, and I said 'yes' to this. Then when I tried to open Boinc I got a message like the following: "You currently are not authorized to manage the client. Either re-install and allow non-admin users or contact your administrator to add you to the 'boinc_master' user group."

So I tried to reinstall first, and I was not asked if non admin users should be allowed to use Boinc.. so I retried a few times and got no different result..

So I downloaded 6.10.43 and installed that, and again I was not asked if non admin users should be allowed to use boinc.. and when I tried to run Boinc I got the same message like: "You currently are not authorized to manage the client. Either re-install and allow non-admin users or contact your administrator to add you to the 'boinc_master' user group."

So I did a Google search trying to figure out how to add my admin user to the bonic_master user group and [found this](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/dev/forum_thread.php?id=4237) which suggested I run the following in terminal:

```
"sudo dscl . -append /Groups/boinc_master GroupMembership <your user's short name> CR"
```

So I did this and now I get the following error:

> BOINC ownership or permissions are not set properly; please reinstall BOINC
>   (Error code -1200)

So I reinstall and I am ever asked the question about allowing non admin users again, and I still get this error message every after every reinstall attempt..

What should I do?

Comment: Can someone create a 'boinc' tag for this question please?

Comment: Done. (10 more to go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this I had to reformat my macbook.

Comment: BOINCs installer is terrible and their permission settings are absurd. There is no excuse for requiring constant reinstalls. I've given up on BOINC since I am tired of having to fix it overtime someone breathes.

Answer (score 0):

Erase everything and reinstall. If you're not running other users don't say "Allow all users." Personally I have had no issues with BOINC running as admin.

I would try [repairing permissions](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aoxn.html) as well as reinstalling.

> 1. To open Disk Utility, from the Applications  folder, open Utilities,
>      and then double-click the Disk Utility
>      icon.
> 2. In the column on the left, click your startup disk.
> 3. Click the First Aid tab, and then click Repair Disk Permissions.
>      Disk Utility will reset any files and
>      folders with incorrect settings.

Comment: Repair permissions only works for files that Apple put on your drive.

Comment: "Erase everything and reinstall. If you're not running other users don't say "Allow all users." Personally I have had no issues with BOINC running as admin."

I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: @Erik: Hmm. "Erase everything and reinstall" would amount to reformatting your MacBook.

Comment: oooh is that what you meant? I thought you ment erase boinc.. you should really say reformat if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Erik: Boinc has issues. A bad install can cause you to have to reinstall the entire system in order to fix it.